# Shorthand for Subversion commit in Confluence/Jira?

Tags: svn, jira, confluence, atlassian-fisheye

Is there a shorthand notation for a Subversion commit in Confluence/Jira? For example, if I am writing a release review blog in Confluence, I might want to say "A problem cause by commit [1234] caused...".

I was hoping for something like {svn|1234}. I have fisheye installed and the plugin installed.

TIA